# Windows Service started, but process vanished in task manager

Tags: windows, windows-services

I programmed a Windows Service and it is running on a Windows 2000 machine. Sometimes the executable for this service dies, but the Windows service is still listed as "started" in the service manager. In this situation the restart behaviour defined for this service does not take effect.

Of course, the process needs to be debugged, but I am searching right now for a workaround.

How can I avoid this situation? How does the service manager in Windows 2000 determine if a windows 2000 process is still started or not?

Answer (score 2):

That probably means that the service crashed.  IIRC, older versions of windows didn't always recover when a service process abnormally terminates.  But that was many years ago and my memory may be faulty.

The best way to avoid the situation is to figure out what's causing your service to crash and fix it.

Comment: Larry: +1. Do you happen to know whether sending `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE` would be a way to point the SCM to the fact that the service process in question has died?

Answer (score 0):

Although Larry, being a Microsoft employee, probably knows better than anyone else, I dare say that you should give `ChangeServiceConfig2` with `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS` a shot. I've worked on a legacy service that, before I did the refactoring, used to crash a lot. The remedy my predecessors chose was to use the failure action in order to invoke a program that (running under SYSTEM) would then restart the service as if nothing had happened.

All of this only works if your service is running in its own process, which I assumed given the way you describe it. If your service is implemented in a DLL this will *not* work.

But I wholeheartedly agree with Larry that you should investigate and fix the problem, rather than trying to conceal it. As mentioned above, I fixed the service in question and it's not crashing or very rarely crashing and everyone is happier with that solution ;)

Comment: I don't think that works - ChangeServiceConfig2 will tell the service controller restart the service (which is a very good thing).  But it relies on the service controller knowing that the service has crashed.